# What is the solution to prevent log file growth due to an AG node issue (other than fixing the node or removing node from AG)?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

In an 2 node AG, suppose one node is not reachable or down or crashed, then the log file size on the primary node will keep growing.

In this situation, is there any way to prevent log growth other than:

1. Removing the other node from AG
2. Fixing the issues with the other node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realistically, those are your only two options. You can, however, remove all of the databases in the AG from the AG - which is essentially, but not quite, the same as dropping the AG entirely which is also another option.

There's no option or setting to "forget about a secondary and keep truncating the log".